# Common name for a public access read-only, but private access read/write variable

Tags: naming-conventions, naming, access-control

A project I work on has many public access read-only, but private access read/write variables. I am looking for a concise (preferably one-word) name for this.

For example, in the following situation, I would like to say "`bar` is a _____ variable".

```cpp
class Foo {
 public:
  const int& GetBar() { return bar; }
 private:
  int bar;
}
```

I've considered:

- `bar` is a "read-only" variable

  - I find this to be inaccurate since it is only read-only in a public context.
- `bar` is a "public read-only" variable

  - I find this to be inaccurate since it does not clarify how it behaves in a private context, and the name is somewhat long.
- `bar` is a "private write" variable

  - This is the best I have come up with. It explains that the variable may only be written to in a private context, and reading in a public context is assumed. However, I think it is still a confusing name.

I'm also fine with coming up with a new name, such as using metaphors to represent the situation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a *read-only exported* variable. However, I don't think it's a good idea to include visibility properties in the variable name, although it's good to have an established terminology in communication with other developers.